# enable asp.net button using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this application where I want to enable asp.net button using javascript. 
JavaScript code:

```
function Enable() {
  document.getElementById('<%= Begin.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
}
```

Asp button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Begin" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
```

I am using ClientScriptBlock to call Enable function:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Begin.Enabled = false;
  ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "EnableButton", "Enable();", true);
}
```

However when I run application I get an error:

> 0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object

Can anyone help me with that?

I want this to check, if user has activated JavaScript on the browser. If JavaScript is not enabled, the button remains disabled.

Comment: What if instead of `RegisterClientScriptBlock` you try `RegisterStartupScript` ?

Comment: Can u see in *rendered* ASPX page what HTML markup for the button looks like? Also, is you JavaScript function embedded into ASPX file or is it in a Separate JS file?

Comment: Is your javascript code in a separate `.js` file?

Comment: @ Yuriy Galanter do you mean this: `<input type="submit" name="Submit"  id="Begin" />` ?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov thx for idea i've put js code inside header and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the javascript code is placed in a separate javascript file. But you seem to have used some `<% %>` server side tags in it which obviously will not be processed. Those tags work only inside your ASPX pages. So I guess that inside your ASPX page you need to declare a variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var beginClientId = '<%= Begin.ClientID %>';
</script>
```

and then inside your separate .js file you could use it:

```
function Enable() {
  document.getElementById(beginClientId).disabled = false;
}
```

Or if you are using ASP.NET 4.0 just turn [`static or predicatble ids`](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/we-lovenet-4-clean-web-control-ids-with-clientidmode-property-to-static-and-predictable):

```
<system.web>
    <pages clientIDMode="Static"></pages>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: If i use this i get `0x800a1391 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'beginClientId' is undefined` error

Comment: That's because you need to include your script **AFTER** the portion which declares the global variable. But it's even better to use static ClientIds.